# Why does Intellij show 'ghost' changes in a multi-modular git project?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, commit

I'm working on a multi-module project with each module being contained in a separate git repo.

When I open the `Commit Changes` dialog in Intellij, alongside changes to `java` files I've made, I often see supposed changes to other modules which haven't in fact changed.

In the change-tree, underneath these unchanged modules, there will be an item with just the name of the git repository, with no file extension, and a question mark icon signifying that Intellij doesn't recognize the file type.

[image: Changes with unknown file type]

When I click on the item, the in-built diff viewer gives `fatal: Not a valid object name` followed by a 40 character hex string.

[image: 40 character hex string, no diff view]

If I revert the changes on that module, it will reappear immediately.

Is there a reason this happens, and will it cause any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks very similar to submodule objects, and the behavior will be like this if you have committed changes in the submodule, but the reference in the root repo has not changed.

Another possible reason is that `git status` outputs the folder as modified, which could happen in case of nested repositories which are not properly ignored in the root repo. In this case, make sure that .gitignore in the root repo contains folders of the nested repos.